# How to get common value based on a column from a table sql

Tags: mysql, sql, count, having-clause, relational-division

I have a table. the screenshot is given bellow:

[image: table]

There have two columns

1. item_details_id
2. pay_method_id

In item_details_id there have 1,2,1 data. On the other hand pay_method_id have 1,1,3 data.

I want to get only common values of pay_method_id depending on item_details_id.

According to the given screenshot-

in item_details_id I have '1' & '2' value.

----- '1' pay_method_id is '1', '3'

----- '2' pay_method_id is '1'

So I have only '1' data is common of pay_method_id

If I give a clean example

suppose a product named laptop has Paypal & Skrill payment method.
another product named desktop has the Skrill Payment method..

So how can I get the common payment method named skrill?

How can I get the value? I can't understand how can I solve this.

Any help will be very helpful to me.

Comment: Could you give an example of the output you'd like?

Comment: so you wat only 1 as result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `pay_method_id`s that have all available `item_details_id`s, you can do:

```
select pay_method_id
from mytable
group by pay_method_id
having count(*) = (select count(distinct item_details_id) from mytable)
```

If there may be duplicate `(pay_method_id, item_details_id)`, then use:

```
having count(distinct item_details_id) = (select count(distinct item_details_id) from mytable)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation:

```
select pay_method_id
from item_pays
where item_details_id in (1, 2)
group by pay_method_id
having count(distinct item_details_id) = 2;
```

This returns all `pay_method_id`s that are common for `item_details_id` `1` and `2`, which is how I interpret your question.

Answer (score 0):

this will check if  items have the same pay

> ```
> CREATE TABLE item_pays (
>   `item_details_id` INTEGER,
>   `pay_method_id` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO item_pays
>   (`item_details_id`, `pay_method_id`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '1'),
>   ('2', '1'),
>   ('1', '3');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT `pay_method_id`
> FROM item_pays
> GROUP BY `pay_method_id`
> HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT `item_details_id`) > 1
> ```
>
> ```
> | pay_method_id |
> | ------------: |
> |             1 |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT `pay_method_id`
> ,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `item_details_id`) items
> FROM item_pays
> GROUP BY `pay_method_id`
> HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT `item_details_id`) > 1
> ```
>
> ```
> pay_method_id | items
> ------------: | :----
>             1 | 1,2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=3f5f4c8d02f28211d98f76c64e656fce)*

Comment: i changed my answer

Comment: It's absolutely fine, but the problem is when I have another item with some payment methods

Comment: your description is hard to grasp and now you make the thinsg more complex, so make a fiddle and showexacty the result set.